# How can I remove jquery from the frontside of my WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My wordpress site is a bit heavy to download. On the frontend, its including jquery unnecessarily. In my firebug it looks like:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.3.2
```

and

```
jquery.form.js?ver=2.02m
```

I don't need these to be included for me.

I'm happy for them to remain in the wp-admin, but I'd like them not to load on the frontend.

I have found the file I think which is loading them in `wp-includes/script-loader.php` but I'm not sure what to uncomment out or what to do to remove it completely for the front.

Is there a way to do this, removing jquery without ruining the back end?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

JQuery may be being added by your theme. If your theme is adding it properly, it should be using the `wp_enqueue_script()` function. To remove JQuery, simply use the `wp_deregister_script()` function.

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

Removing JQuery for your whole site might cause some unintended consequences for your admin section. To avoid removing JQuery on your admin pages, use this code instead:

```
if ( !is_admin() ) wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

Now only pages that are not admin pages will run the `wp_deregister_script()` function.

Add this code to the functions.php file in your theme directory.

Comment: This is now out of date. please see my solution below.

Comment: yep. doesn't work anymore. deweydb's answer is correct.

Comment: but it also removes plugin's js

Comment: I'm unsure, and the docs are also, what wp_deregister_script or wp_dequeue_script do.  WordPress is a mess.

Answer (score 52):

The correct method to completely remove a style or script is to dequeue it **and** deregister it. You should also note that front end scripts are handled through the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook while back end scripts are handled through the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook.

So with that in mind, you can do the following

```
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'change_default_jquery', PHP_INT_MAX );

function change_default_jquery( ){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery');
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery');   
}
```

**EDIT 1**

This has been fully tested on Wordpress version 4.0 and working as expected.

**EDIT 2**

As proof of concept, paste the following code in your functions.php. This will print a success or failure message in the head of your site, back end and front end

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'check_jquery' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'check_jquery' );
function check_jquery() {

    global $wp_scripts;

    foreach ( $wp_scripts->registered as $wp_script ) {
        $handles[] = $wp_script->handle; 
    }

    if( in_array( 'jquery', $handles ) ) {
        echo 'jquery has been loaded';
    }else{
        echo 'jquery has been removed';
    }
}
```

Comment: it also removes all plugin's js

Comment: June 2017: I rolled parts of this answer into a plugin: https://github.com/jonathanbell/remove-jquery-wordpress-plugin

Comment: I made an open source plugin for WP with a lot of settings to manage jQuery on WP: https://github.com/Remzi1993/wp-jquery-manager

Comment: I'm puzzled. two function calls to remove a script?

Answer (score 38):

All the other solutions are now out of date as of wordpress 3.6

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'change_default_jquery' );

function change_default_jquery( &$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()){
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery');
        $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), '1.10.2' );
    }
}
```

Comment: At last! Thank you.

Comment: Is this still the best way as of 5.0?

Answer (score 7):

Wordpress adds this jQuery call via a template tag named `<?php wp_head(); ?>`, which appears in most themes, and is necessary for some plugins to work.

It could be annoying, not only because of loading, but because it might kill previously loaded jQuery, and might even get in the way of some plugins who try to load jQuery as well.

The quick fix is openning up the file header.php in your theme's directory, and adding:

```
<?php wp_deregister_script('jquery'); ?>
```

right before

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Or just combine them both into:

```
<?php wp_deregister_script('jquery'); wp_head(); ?>
```

A more technical explanation could be found [here](http://falcon1986.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/remove-unwanted-wordpress-header-elements/)

Comment: Please, promise me you will never get near a WordPress install

Answer (score 4):

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', false);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

It's correct - removes jquery library js. Code from other answers removes all js (even js that your installed plugins adds)

Tested on 4.3.1

Answer (score 4):

### WordPress 5 and above (*Tested*)

Remove the default jquery and add your jquery from folder or from CDN. Use only one, 'local' or 'cdn'

```
// Remove the WordPress default jquery
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

// using a local file
wp_enqueue_script(
  'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js','', '3.3.1', true
);

// using CDN
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', '', '3.3.1', true
);

// $handle: 'jquery'
// $src: 
    // local: get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
    // cdn: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'
// $deps: '' (leave it empty)
// $ver: '3.3.1'
// $in_footer: true (boolean)
```

#### Syntax

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into your theme files.

> wp-content/themes/header.php

may include the .js files.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the Wordpress theme. jQuery used on admin panel (wp-admin) OR jQuery used in product page. to speed up. this will work. Tested on WP 5.0
jQuery only load if admin is logged in or its product page (its doesn't matter user logged in or not on product page. (jQuery load on product page))

```
function my_jquery_remove() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && !is_product() ) {
       wp_deregister_script('jquery');
       wp_register_script('jquery', false);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_jquery_remove');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the source of your rendered page; Wordpress often includes jQuery by default when `<?php wp_head(); ?>`  is called in header.php, so you may stil see jQuery included in your site.

If you remove  `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.php, you might loose other plugin functionality, as many plugins "hook" into Wordpress at that point.

But including jQuery isn't that big of a deal. It's small and Wordpress depends on it for some things.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to shave 2.2 seconds off my "Events" page load speed by de-registering jQuery. jQuery is a nice to have but in my opinion page speed is so much more important.

You'll never have a user hang around for more than 5 seconds so if jQuery is causing you performance problems, then I say get rid.

Comment: Agreed. Build everything up to not require it, and use it only if you must. Seconds are a huge deal. It's not just download, it's also processing time.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery.js is just 15KB if you're using the minified version, and these would be totally absent if you were using a theme that doesn't require it.

You should probably look for a lightweight theme without jQuery instead of hacking it and then seeing the theme break in several places because they're looking for those js files.

Comment: jQuery.js is roughly that size if you use the minified version **and** you compress the data with GZip.

jQuery.form.js is 22K uncompressed and unminified.

Comment: 15KB vs. 22KB won't be a noticeable difference, methinks.