# wp_dequeue_script VS Deleting the script from functions.php

Tags: javascript, wordpress

firstly please pardon my complete ignorance in regards to Wordpress and Web Development in general if in being completely honest.

I have a theme on my website which came with a whole bunch of Javascript addons (like pretty photo) that i dont want. There are literally tons of them. Now, i want to remove the relevant files altogether, but that will result in 404 on those files (which wont help with my load times).

My question, i have been reading an aweful lot about `wp_dequeue_script` , and how it removes files. 
Why not just delete the actual `wp_enqueue_` files from `function.php`??

Does that cause problems? Any insight into the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Wordpress.

> Why not just delete the actual wp_enqueue_ files from function.php??

The only answer and explanation to this question is, if you are not the author of a plugin or theme, never make any type of modification to that plugin or theme. This also goes for Wordpress core files. The simple reason being, if you ever upgrade your theme/plugin/core, all your changes will be lost and cannot be retrieved. This is a very costly mistake

### The proper way

In your case, you should use functions like `wp_deregister_script()` and `wp_dequeue_script()` to remove scripts you don't need. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27048128/1908141) on how to correctly remove scripts.

This functions should go in either a [custom plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) or a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). This should never go into the theme directly as this will be deleted when you update your theme.

I hope this helps

Comment: In my case wp_dequeue_script or wp_dequeue_style has no effect. The scripts or styles are included non the less. Is this due to an ill behaving plugin/theme or a design flaw in wordpress. I spend 4 hours to remove a script from the queue but is still is showing up. The culprtt is https://wordpress.org/themes/activello/